# Do free electrons in a crystal reflect off lattice planes?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, electric-current, diffraction

My textbook (Arthur Beiser Intro to Modern Physics) states that "unbound low-energy electrons can travel freely through a crystal since their wave lengths are long relative to the lattice spacing $a$" in the chapter on solid state physics.

Now I understand that high-energy electrons with wavelengths comparable to the lattice spacing $a$ will undergo diffraction (just like x-rays diffract when they impinge upon a crystal). Hence these electrons will not be able to travel freely through the lattice. Clearly this *diffraction* will not occur for low-energy electrons with wavelengths much longer than $a$. But surely these low-energy electrons will still *reflect* off the lattice planes in the same way that visible light *reflects* off a crystal (as opposed to x-rays which diffract off the lattice)? The fact that the low energy electrons have wavelengths much longer than $a$ doesn't seem to indicate that they should be able to travel freely through the lattice because they should still be *reflecting* off the planes of lattice points within the solid just like visible light reflects off the surface of a crystal when it is incident on the surface of that crystal. So why does the author infer that low energy electrons should be able to travel freely through the crystal?

Any help on this issue would be most appreciated!

Comment: 'unbound low-energy electrons' Probably the author means electrons close to the conduction band minimum, which he takes as the zero of the energy scale.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by 'unbound low-energy electrons' the author means electrons close to a conduction band minimum and that he takes this a the reference of the energy scale.

Near a minimum the conduction band has parabolic shape so that the energy momentum relation there is $E = p^2/m^* = \hbar^2 k^2 / m^*$. Under these conditions an electron behaves like a free electron with effective mass $m^*$. This is probably what the author is referring to. Note that the effective mass can be quite different from the vacuum electron mass.